# Write two JSON entries from one Java field

Tags: java, gson

### The Problem:

I have a bunch of `DTOs` with a structure like this:

```
public class Foobar {
    private String name;
    private Timestamp time1;
    private Timestamp time2;
    private int value;
}
```

I need to serialize the `Timestamps` to **two separate** values (one time call `.toString()` and one time formatted according to ISO standard) in order to be backward compatible with old API and also support a decent time format from now on.

So the `JSON` output for Foobar should look like this:

```
{
    "name":"<some name>",
    "time1":"<some non standard time>",
    "iso_time1":"<ISO formatted time>",
    "time2":"<some non standard time>",
    "iso_time2":"<ISO formatted time>",
    "value":<some number>
}
```

I am restricted to Gson due to existing code.

### Question:

Is it possible to do this in a generic way, that will work for all my `DTOs` **without changing the `DTOs`**?

I want to avoid having to write a `TypeAdapter/Serializer/new DTO` for each of my existing DTOs.

### What I tried

**TypeAdapter**

I already tried to do it via a `TypeAdapter` and `TypeAdapterFactory` but I need the field name of the class in order to distinguish the two timestamps.

`write(...)` method of the `TypeAdapter` illustrating the issue I had with it (`T extends Timestamp`):

```
@Override
public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) throws IOException {
    out.value(value.toString());
    out.name(TIMESTAMP_ISO_PREFIX + fieldName).value(toISOFormat(value));
}
```

The Problem here is, that I did not find any way to get to the field name. I tried to get it with a `TypeAdapterFactory` but the factory does not know the field name either.

**JsonSerializer**

I also tried to do it via `JsonSerializer`, but it is not possible to return two JSON elements and returning a JsonObject would break existing API.

Comment: Can you show the code for JsonSerializer you have implemented?

Comment: What are the conditions for including the fields in the first place? Are they actually `private`?

Comment: A `TypeAdapter` seems like a reasonable solution. What trouble did you run in to?

Comment: @pirho I did not implement anything with the `JsonSerializer`as I need to return 2 `JsonElement`s and the `serialize(...)` method does only return one.

Comment: @Marco13 Could you explain the first question?
They are `private` with getter/setter methods.

Comment: @teppic See updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach 1: Use a `JsonSerialiser`

You can create a `JsonSerialiser` for your objects (i.e. one level higher than the `Timestamp`) and use it to append extra fields as needed:

```
/**
 * Appends extra fields containing ISO formatted times for all Timestamp properties of an Object.
 */
class TimestampSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Object> {
    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonElement tree = gson.toJsonTree(src);
        if (tree instanceof JsonObject) {
            appendIsoTimestamps(src, (JsonObject) tree);
        }
        return tree;
    }

    private JsonObject appendIsoTimestamps(Object src, JsonObject object) {
        try {
            PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(src.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors();
            for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : descriptors) {
                if (descriptor.getPropertyType().equals(Timestamp.class)) {
                    Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) descriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(src);
                    object.addProperty("iso_" + descriptor.getName(), ts.toInstant().toString());
                }
            }
            return object;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | IntrospectionException e) {
            throw new JsonIOException(e);
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
public class GsonSerialiserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Foobar.class, new TimestampSerializer());
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        Foobar baz = new Foobar("baz", 1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(baz));
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- This example uses the java bean introspector to find `Timestamp` properties. It relies on the presence of getter methods. If you don't have getters you'll have to use some other method to read your timestamp properties.
- The serialiser delegates to another gson builder (it can't call the one in the `JsonSerializationContext` or it would end up calling itself recursively). If your existing serialisation relies on other instrumentation in the builder you'll have to wire up a separate builder and pass it to the serialiser.

If you want to do this for *all* objects you're serialising register the adapter for the entire `Object` hierarchy:

```
builder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Object.class, typeAdapter);
```

If you just want to modify a subset of DTOs you can register them dynamically. The [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library makes this easy:

```
TimestampSerializer typeAdapter = new TimestampSerializer();

Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false))
    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader()))
    .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().includePackage("com.package.dto", "com.package.other")));

Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

for (Class<?> type : classes) {
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(type, typeAdapter);
}
```

The example above registers everything in the named packages. If your DTOs conform to a naming pattern or implement a common interface/have a common annotation you could further restrict what gets registered.

### Approach 2: Register a `TypeAdapterFactory`

`TypeAdapters` work at the reader/writer level and require a little more work to implement, but they give you more control.

Registering a `TypeAdapterFactory` with the builder will allow you to control which types to edit. This example applies the adapter to all types:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

    builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
        public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
            // Return null here if you don't want to handle the type.
            // This example returns an adapter for every type.
            return new TimestampAdapter<>(type);
        }
    });

    Gson gson = builder.create();
    Foobar baz = new Foobar("baz", 1);
    String json = gson.toJson(baz);
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(gson.fromJson(json, Foobar.class));
}
```

And the adapter...

```
class TimestampAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {
    private TypeToken<T> type;
    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public TimestampAdapter(TypeToken<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        JsonObject object = appendIsoTimestamps(value, (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(value));
        TypeAdapters.JSON_ELEMENT.write(out, object);
    }

    private JsonObject appendIsoTimestamps(T src, JsonObject tree) {
        try {
            PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(src.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors();
            for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : descriptors) {
                if (descriptor.getPropertyType().equals(Timestamp.class)) {
                    Timestamp ts = (Timestamp) descriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(src);
                    tree.addProperty("iso_" + descriptor.getName(), ts.toInstant().toString());
                }
            }
            return tree;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | IntrospectionException e) {
            throw new JsonIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T read(JsonReader in) {
        return gson.fromJson(in, type.getType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I like, that I don't need to implement a serializer for each `DTO`, but I would still need to register all my `DTO`s with the builder (`GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter`) and running the risk of missing one.
I don't think there is actually a way to catch all `Timestamps` of **all** `Objects`... If I don't find a more generic way I will accept this answer

Comment: If you want to do this for all objects the serialiser handles, use `builder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Object.class, typeAdapter);`. It's also possible to register packages dynamically with a little work. I've updated the answer with notes on registration.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple, short, and DTO-driven solution is to create a second getter/setter with a different name for the same field.

```
public class SerializationTest {

    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() { return foo; }

    // getter for json serialization
    public String getBar() { return foo; }
}
```

You might have to modify serialization settings for this to work, something like this:

```
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);
```

Also note that this approach has potential pitfalls, for example when deserializing - two setters might set the same variable to a different value.